# Why does unmanaged code increments memory to a specific limit?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, unmanaged

I work with a flow control system written in. NET, the system inter-acts with external systems through TCP connections and routes transactions between different endpoints.

**My problem:**

At startup / initialization the private working set memory level is about 25000KB. After initialization when the system is in idle state, the private working set is stepping up with about 50-100KB per second until it reaches a limit of about 57000KB.

**Information:**

The system is generating page faults during the incrementation.

When the limit is reached, the private working set stays very stable and oscillates up and down with a few MB when I connect +300 clients and exchange high-frequency transactions for a couple of hours, the logic for garbage collection works very well.

I have profiled this system with a tool from Redgate called "Memory Profiler" which tells me the memory stepping up after initialization is allocated by unmanaged code, unfortunately this profiler does not support insight to memory allocated by unmanaged code so I have difficulties to find out what this allocated memory contains, why it is allocated and which code that allocates the memory.

The whole codebase is developed in C#, there are no references to COM+ assemblies and there is no communication with native windows API's (during the incrementation of this memory).

**My question:**

I need to be pointed in the right direction to find out why the memory is continuously incrementing in small chunks to a specific level after initialization.

Comment: _"through TCP connections [...] no communication with native windows API's."_ - you rebuilt WinSock while you were at it? ;-)

Comment: There is no communication with native API's during the incrementation of this memory, (my question has now been edited with that info).

Comment: @Tobias You may want to try [_.Net Memory Profiler_](http://memprofiler.com/). It can track unmanaged memory, and there's a free trial available.

Comment: @Dzienny Thank you! I will test this profiler, darn that Redgate does not support transparency in unmanaged code, my employer has just purchased their entire software suite.

Answer (score 1):

If a page is in not working set this does not mean the page is stored only on disk or on disk at all. Pages on Windows can go to the *standby list*. If they do, they leave the WS and require a *soft fault* to bring them back. (I never understood why this mechanism is there, but it is). A soft fault is cheap.

Using Process Explorer's system information window you can see the number of hard and soft faults per seconds. Probably also available using perfmon. I suggest you check if you have hard faults (which I believe you don't so you don't have a problem and you can close the investigation).

Also, WS has nothing to do with memory usage, but I think you already knew that.

Comment: Thank you for the information, the page faults generated is soft fault.

Comment: @Tobias you're good then. It is not a perf problem and part of the generally mysterious memory manager decisions on Windows.